# run bash (command line) inside Emacs text editor?

Tags: sql, bash, command-line, emacs

i want to run command line inside emacs text editor .

i have just finished the emacs tutorial i want to practice in some SQL files and i need the command line near to me to see SQL changes and results 
any idea ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because emacs.stackexchange.com would be a better site.

Comment: See [this question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/241/11) about all the ways to start a shell inside Emacs.

Comment: @Barmar: SO is just as good a site as emacs.stackexchange, for Emacs questions.

Comment: @Drew If it's about programming Emacs macros or using it as an IDE, sure. But questions about using Emacs for shell stuff seems OT. emacs.SE, unix.SE, or SuperUser seem better.

Comment: Mustapha Elbazi: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlMode -- You don't even *need* a shell to interactively query a database and see the results from within Emacs. You can edit your SQL in one buffer, and then send selected queries directly to a `sql-interactive-mode` buffer, which executes the query and shows you the results.

Comment: e.g. try opening a .sql file, then use the SQL -> Product menu to select the database you're using, followed by the SQL -> Start SQLi session option to connect to the database. `C-h m` in the original SQL buffer to see how to send queries.

Comment: @Barmar: It doesn't seem OT to me. And you don't say why it seems so to you. Anyway, AFAIK there is no such SE policy to close questions, and there is no such migration path from here to there.

Comment: @Drew It's OT because it has nothing to do with programming. It's about using Emacs as a terminal emulator.

Comment: @Barmar: And why would that be OT for SO?

Comment: @Drew Are you trying to be sarcastic? SO is about programming, it's not at all about programming. It's no more on-topic than a question about using Terminal.

Comment: @Barmar: No, I'm not being sarcastic. Please explain why "*questions about using Emacs for shell stuff seems OT*". Or not. I think we've both expressed our points of view already.

Comment: @Drew Not sure how to explain a negative. It's off-topic simply because it's not ON topic. SO Is about programming, what does running shell commands in Emacs have to do with programming? I know that Emacs is used for programming (I use it myself), but that doesn't make everything about Emacs on-topic here. We also use terminal emulators to compile programs, but that doesn't make terminal emulators on-topic.

Comment: There have been meta discussions about Emacs in the past (pre-Emacs.SE), and my interpretation of those at the time (none of them reached any official decision) was that Emacs *in general* was on-topic for SO. Now that we have the SE site there may be a stronger argument for deciding otherwise (and I've not checked meta in more recent times), but if that decision hasn't been made, then all Emacs questions are still on-topic for SO so far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There you have some tips how to or basicaly run 2 terminals on one Computer(Subshells)](http://www.nongnu.org/emacsdoc-fr/manuel/shell.html)

or [GNU documentation website of emacs with some valuable links for shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html)

Comment: thanks i find what i  want